# App icon is not working for iPad retina and iPad retina 64bit

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have uploaded three app icons which can support both iPhone and iPad but when i am running my app in iPad retina or iPad retina 64bit its showing default app icon instead of the uploaded image.

[image: respective app icons for my app]

Comment: those icons are for iPhone... every label says _iPhone_... where are the _iPad_ icons?

Answer (score 0):

For iPad you need to set the App icon of Size 76X76 pixels for iOS 7.0 and above also its 2x must be present for retina